# Missing AdActivity with android:configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I am building an app and I wanted to add ad banners to the game when I run it instead of getting adds I am getting a banner that says"Missing AdActivity with android:configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml" I have tried searching online for the problem but it seems that what the people say to fix the problem I already have corrected. Please help

**What I put in my Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.unity3d.player"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screen      Layout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
       android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScr eenSize"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Can you post your entire Manifest here in case the problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: @VenkatatAxiomStudios entire Manifest is now posted

Answer (score 0):

Your Manifest is malformed.

The `uses-permission` elements need to reside within the `manifest` element and before the `supports-screen` element.

Comment: post your Activity layout, your activity code and your logcat.